# How to display top-down 2D online game

Tags: browser-based-games, online

I'm new to game development (but not new to software development). As a personal/learning project, I'm designing an overhead-view 2D online RTS game (static, no scrolling). The first cut will pretty much only require simple sprites, with typical menus, text, and buttons.

Most of the game logic will happen server-side, with unit positions and other vitals sent to the browser at about 30 fps. The client won't do much, aside from the display and UI.
The server stuff is easy for me, but I need a little guidance on the browser display.

Having read up on several new browser technologies/HTML5 libraries, I'm getting more overwhelmed by the options, not less! I don't necessarily need the absolute best tool; what I want is a technology that will make it easy to implement a simple sprite-based game, and do a decent job of it.

I know JS itself well enough, but not any of the fancy graphics/game libraries. I know Flash/AS3 (doing what I want in Flash would be easy enough, but the mobile browser support concerns me--should I steer clear if I want iOS support?). I have the entire Adobe suite (subscription), if that helps. I'm not averse to learning a new language/API/tool, of course, but the more I can put what I know to good use, the better.

So, my question (yes, there is one in here somewhere!) is, what are my (best) options today for implementing the in-browser (display) part of said 2D online browser-based game, based on the above goals and stated skillset/available tools? Since it may be difficult to be completely objective, please do include a little rationale on why you believe your answer is the right tool for this job. I'm not asking for a doctoral thesis, here, just a paragraph or two. :-)

Comment: What technologies or languages are you familiar with?

Comment: I believe I outlined that in the question, or are you asking something else? I guess I could add that I have a tiny bit of experience with jQuery, but very little, which is why I didn't include it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [this, the speaker is giving an overview over different technologies](http://de.slideshare.net/vincent_scheib/html5-and-other-modern-browser-game-tech).

I have done some small games with [HTML Canvas](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) and found it very easy to pick up. I think it should be sufficent for your amount of sprites.

If you program your game with HTML and JS is should be quite easy to port it for mobile platforms. Again I was able to port a browserbased game into a native Windows 8 Store game with just one line of code change.

If you want to dig a bit deeper into game engines I suggest you take a look at [this overview](https://github.com/bebraw/jswiki/wiki/Game-Engines), most of tem are JS based and can offer you some nice additions.

Answer (score 0):

hm, quite a lot of ambition for your first game. Most people find tetris a challenging enough game to implement when they don't have experience with game engines. That being said; I would probably go for simple jQuery and maybe something a plain as gifs for animations.

I am fully aware that HTML5/CSS3 provides better functionality though, but that is beyond my experience (I have mostly done XNA games)